# Converting IPAddress[] to string

Tags: c#, httplistener

I've got a server application which I'm trying to automatically set the IP address to, taken from the machine's dynamically allocated IP address. So far I've got this to get the IPv4 but it's returned as type IPAddress[] which I have some trouble converting to a string[] so my HttpListener can use it. Any hint to how I can convert it? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

This is what I'm using to get the IP address:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string name = (args.Length < 1) ? Dns.GetHostName() : args[0];
        try
        {
            IPAddress[] addrs = Array.FindAll(Dns.GetHostEntry(string.Empty).AddressList,
                a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
            Console.WriteLine("Your IP address is: ");
            foreach (IPAddress addr in addrs)
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", name, addr);

            //Here I'm trying to convert the IPAddress[] into a string[] to use in my listener
            string str = addrs.ToString();
            string[] ipString = { str };
            Response.Listener(ipString);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        //current way of setting the IP address - not optimal
        string[] ipstring = new string[1] {"10.10.180.11:8080"};
        Response.Listener(ipstring);


    }

}
```

And the listener for good times sake:

```
 public static void Listener(string[] prefixes)
    {
        if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Windows XP SP2 or Server 2003 is required to use the HttpListener class.");
            return;
        }
        // URI prefixes are required, 
        // for example "http://contoso.com:8080/index/".
        if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");


        // Create a listener.
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        // Add the prefixes. 
        foreach (string s in prefixes)
        {
            listener.Prefixes.Add("http://" + s + "/");
        }

        listener.Start();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
string[] ips = addresses.Select(ip => ip.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Make sure you have a using statement for `System.Linq`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to convert an IPAdress's array like one IPAdress.

You can use LINQ to convert each IPAdress, then you can make the String's array :

```
String[] strAddrs = (from cad in addrs select cad.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Don't forget : `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `IPAddress` object, you can get the string representation like this:

**v4:**

```
validIP4.MapToIPv4().ToString();
```

**v6:**

```
validIP4.MapToIPv6().ToString();
```